# how to check UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, type-conversion

does anyone know conversion to this 
if (&UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification && &UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification) {
} in swift

Comment: Where you want to use it?. It seems bit confusing to me.

Comment: There's no need for this at all. Those symbols were added back in iOS 4. So unless you are trying to support iOS 3.2 or earlier (highly unlikely), there is no reason at all in either Swift or Objective-C to be checking to see if those symbols exist.

Answer (score 0):

This might work on your side.

```
var didEnterBackgroundNotificationName = NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground.rawValue
var willEnterForgroundNotificationName = NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground.rawValue
let address1 : Int = address(of: &didEnterBackgroundNotificationName)
let address2 : Int = address(of: &willEnterForgroundNotificationName)

if address1 != 0 && address2 != 0 {
    // code here
}
```